# How is infrared light created?

Tags: optics, infrared-radiation

All mass with a temperature creates infrared light, but what is the cause of this? How is it created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matter consists of multiple atoms. Temperature is a measure for how fast these atoms are moving on average:

$$v \propto \sqrt{\frac{k_B T}{m}}$$

With the Boltzmann constant $k_b$, temperature $T$ and mass $m$.

Every atom is surrounded by electron orbitals that have a discrete angular momentum. If energy is transmitted to one electron e.g. via collision it can move to a higher orbital (excitation) or even be ionized. This leaves a hole in the former spot, which will be reoccupied by an electron from a higher level. Because it takes energy to move an electron to higher levels, energy gets released once the lower level is reoccupied. The energy gets released as a photon with frequency $f$ which is correlated to the energy via $E=h f$, with Planck constant $h$.

For the right energy differences between orbitals this leads to infrared radiation. The energy needed to excite an electron comes from the collisions from the atoms inside matter.

Comment: What happens if you just have one atom? How does it it emit thermal radiation?

Comment: It doesn't. One atom is not a thermal medium

Comment: It’s in detailed balance with it environment at thermal equilibrium; it emits at the same the rate it absorbs. So a single atom must still emit thermal radiation. To be clear I am thinking of a single atom interacting with photon gas of a finite temperature.

Comment: If it has an environment there is more than a single atom. The energy required can not only come from collisions but also from radiation. So an atom can absorb an earlier emitted photon which is exactly the energy needed to excite one of its electrons.

Comment: So , I assume that matter with enough heat will produce visible light instead, but does that mean that cold enough matter will create microwaves or radio waves?

Comment: Yes. If you use high velocity electrons and shoot them on target material, you can even create x-rays. That is how the machines operate.

Comment: Also, if you heat up materials you can see them glowing. That's your visible light ;)

Comment: @infinitezero thanks for your help :)